# Why is this the parametrization?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, area

I am looking at the following:

Let $0\leq a<b$ and the function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with continuous derivatve at $[a,b]$.

Draw the graph of $f$ at $xz$-plane and the surface that we get by total rotation of the graph around the $z$-axis. 
See why that surface can be parametrized by the function $\Sigma (u,v)=(u\cos v, u\sin v, f(u))$, $u\in [a,b]$, $v\in [0,2\pi]$ and calculate its area.

$$$$

So, do we have to draw an arbitrary function that has a continuous derivative on an interval?

Can we take for example $f(x)=x^2$ ?

When we rotate that function, why can we parametrize the surface that we get by $\Sigma (u,v)=(u\cos v, u\sin v, f(u))$. I haven't understood that. Could you explain it to me?

The area is equal to \begin{align*}\iint_D\|\Sigma_u\times\Sigma_v\|dudv&=\iint_D\sqrt{u^2(f'(u))^2+u^2}dudv=\iint_D\sqrt{u^2\left ((f'(u))^2+1\right )}dudv \\ & =\iint_Du^2\sqrt{(f'(u))^2+1}dudv=\int_a^b\int_0^{2\pi}u^2\sqrt{(f'(u))^2+1}dvdu\\ & =2\pi\int_a^bu^2\sqrt{(f'(u))^2+1}du\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$(u,v)$ are in fact polar coordinates, usually denoted as $(\rho,\theta)$. Together with $z$, this gives a cylindrical coordinate system.

The surface of revolution is obtained rotating the 2D graph $(u,f(u))$ over the $z$ axis, by varying $v$. In Cartesian coordinates,

$$(u\cos v,u\sin v,f(u)).$$

Comment: So, we obtain the suface by rotating the 2D graph $(u, f(u))$ around the $z$-axis and $v$ is a free variable? In cartesian coordinates we have that $(x,y,z)=(u\cos v, u\sin v, f(u))$, since $x=u\cos v, y=u\sin v$ are the polar coordinates and we have the function $z=f(u)$ ?